# Socket.IO attempting to connect through https:// instead of wss:// and getting a CORS error

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, cors

I'm switching from `JavaScript's` vanilla `WebSocket` API to `Socket.IO` for real-time data about `cryptocurrency` prices. While using the regular `WebSocket` I had no problem connecting to `Kraken` and getting the data I need. However, when trying to connect with `Socket.IO`, I get a `CORS` error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ws.kraken.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mxg8_5_' from origin  has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In in the Chrome dev tools network tab, I'm getting an `Invalid request` response from `Kraken`. I assume `Socket.IO` is trying to send some sort of preflight request when trying to establish a `websocket` connection and failing due to `Kraken's` `CORS` policy for http requests. Is there a way to completely bypass this `XMLHttpRequest` attempt and immediately try a `websocket` connection, seeing as the regular `WebSocket` API has no issues establishing this connection and doesn't seem to send a preflight request? Here are both the vanilla and the `Socket.IO` sockets:

```
// vanilla websocket
const vanillaWS = new WebSocket('wss://ws.kraken.com');
vanillaWS.onopen = () => {
  console.log('vanilla websocket opened');
}
vanillaWS.onmessage = (message) => {
  console.log(message.data);
}

// socket.io websocket
const ioSocket = io('wss://ws.kraken.com');
ioSocket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('socket.io socket opened');
});
ioSocket.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log(message.data);
});
```

As you can see, these should be functionally very similar, but while the first one works as expected, the second one is throwing the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/):

> **What Socket.IO is not**
>
> Socket.IO is NOT a WebSocket implementation. Although Socket.IO indeed
>   uses WebSocket as a transport when possible, it adds some metadata to
>   each packet: the packet type, the namespace and the packet id when a
>   message acknowledgement is needed. That is why a WebSocket client will
>   not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server, and **a
>   Socket.IO client will not be able to connect to a WebSocket server
>   either**. Please see the protocol specification
>   [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol).

So if the endpoint you're trying to use isn't running a Socket.IO server, this isn't going to work.

That said, if it is, you can force the use of websockets using the `transports` parameter:

```
const ioSocket = io(endpoint, {
  transports: ['websocket']  // forces websockets only
});
```

**Bottom Line**: Socket.IO is not a replacement for a WebSockets connection. Socket.IO uses WebSockets to accomplish its goal: *"Socket.IO is a library that enables real-time, bidirectional and event-based communication between the browser and the server"*.

Comment: Thank you, shortly after posting this issue I read that Socket.IO is required on both sides in order for the real-time connection to work. I tried naively using it as a replacement for JS's WebSocket because it came as a requirement for this project, however I now see that there'll be some work required on the backend as well. The final goal is for the backend to connect to Kraken and the client to connect to the backend API but I was trying to connect directly to Kraken for testing purposes before moving on. I see now that it's not that straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the CORS error because socket.io attempts pure HTTP-based long-polling connection first and that's what fails. You should manually set your client to attempt websocket first:

```js
var options = {
            allowUpgrades: true,
            transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
        };
        var sock = io(server, options);
        sock.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('socket.io socket opened');
        });
        sock.on('message', (message) => {
            console.log(message.data);
        });
```

From the [socket.io docs](https://socket.io/docs/client-api#With-websocket-transport-only):

> With websocket transport only
>
> By default, a long-polling connection is established first, then
>   upgraded to “better” transports (like WebSocket). If you like to live
>   dangerously, this part can be skipped:
>
> const socket = io({   transports: ['websocket'] });
>
> // on reconnection, reset the transports option, as the Websocket //
>   connection may have failed (caused by proxy, firewall, browser, ...)
>   socket.on('reconnect_attempt', () => {   socket.io.opts.transports =
>   ['polling', 'websocket']; });